# Minecraft server not turning on

Tags: minecraft

Whenever I try to run my creative server I immediately get this error and I have no clue what to do.
It just crashes and I have no clue how to fix it
Stack overflow keeps asking for more detail which is why this line is here

```
Encountered an unexpected exception
net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.ReportedException: Exception while ticking
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1117) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:355) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1007) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:846) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerChunk.a(PlayerChunk.java:127) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.ChunkProviderServer.flagDirty(ChunkProviderServer.java:451) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.notify(WorldServer.java:1217) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.block.CraftBlockState.update(CraftBlockState.java:185) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.block.CraftBlockState.update(CraftBlockState.java:167) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.event.CraftEventFactory.handleBlockSpreadEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:751) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.BlockFire.tickAlways(BlockFire.java:216) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.BlockBase$BlockData.a(BlockBase.java:539) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.b(WorldServer.java:635) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickListServer.b(TickListServer.java:79) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.doTick(WorldServer.java:337) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1104) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    ... 5 more
[20:23:48] [Server thread/ERROR]:   Cause of unexpected exception was
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerChunk.a(PlayerChunk.java:127) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.ChunkProviderServer.flagDirty(ChunkProviderServer.java:451) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.notify(WorldServer.java:1217) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.block.CraftBlockState.update(CraftBlockState.java:185) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.block.CraftBlockState.update(CraftBlockState.java:167) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.event.CraftEventFactory.handleBlockSpreadEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:751) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.BlockFire.tickAlways(BlockFire.java:216) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.BlockBase$BlockData.a(BlockBase.java:539) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.b(WorldServer.java:635) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickListServer.b(TickListServer.java:79) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.WorldServer.doTick(WorldServer.java:337) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1104) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:355) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1007) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:846) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.4.jar:git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
[20:23:48] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: C:\Users\Ball Fondlers\OneDrive\Desktop\Creative-Server\.\crash-reports\crash-2021-01-26_20.23.48-server.txt
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Disabling Essentials v2.18.2.0
[20:23:48] [Server thread/ERROR]: There's a good chance you're reloading your server right now. If that's the case, why do you hate yourself? Expect no support from the EssentialsX team when using /reload.
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Disabling WorldEdit v7.2.1+299386a
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: Unregistering com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitServerInterface from WorldEdit
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: [LuckPerms] Disabling LuckPerms v5.2.76
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: [LuckPerms] Starting shutdown process...
[20:23:48] [Server thread/INFO]: [LuckPerms] Closing storage...
[20:23:48] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: Disconnecting com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile@6bf376de[id=2c6436fc-5188-4027-b4c4-6356a25af962,name=MoreEqualThanYou,properties={textures=[com.mojang.authlib.properties.Property@28c080e]},legacy=false] (/127.0.0.1:57042): Failed to verify username!
[20:23:48] [User Authenticator #1/WARN]: Exception verifying MoreEqualThanYou
```

Comment: ik that it is caused by the indexout of range exception but I have no clue what part of the code is causing it

Answer (score 0):

We need all of the code, Do not cut off parts of it.

**A list of your plugins**

We need to see all plugins you have installed.

Spigot version:
Paste the output of running /version on your server WITH the Minecraft version. latest is not a version; we require the output of /version so we can properly track down the issue.

Comment: I have EssentialsX-2.18.2.0, LuckPerms-Bukkit-5.2.76, and worldedit-bukkit-7.2.1
I am running git-Spigot-37d799b-3eb7236 (MC: 1.16.4) and this is the entire latest.log
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RmgoZot89KnQkqb4sw2_ea1WY0jLfVfYX-L7hv8dIqk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TheUltimateDog Edit your code log with an entire start up log.

Comment: and it doesn't run long enough for /version

Comment: @TheUltimateDog You have a corrupted chunk. Try removing your world and saving it in a file on your desktop and let the server generate a new world and see if it works.